# Fixed resolution

Tags: resolution, games

When I start apps that change my screen resolution, it keeps unchanged after exiting the app. (games in Wine, some linux games: World of Goo, Enemy Territory) Also sometimes I can see the panels and those made weird resolution (1440*8XX). Then I have to get the resolution back to native every time I close an app. Can I fix the desktop resolution not to be attracted by the apps?
In Enemy Territory I have another problem, changing resolution moved my screen so I couldnt see anything, only a part of the wallpaper. I cant play ET on native resolution because it goes over the size of my monitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type in terminal

```
xrandr -s 0
```

It should revert back to default resolution/refreshrate.
You can also add this command to Unity launcher :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! But in my case (12.04 LTS), it works only temporarily. If restart or turn off the netbook, or even if it get is stand by mode, when it start again, the resolution is bad. Since the day when one stupid game ruined my resolution, I have to actually write this command line every day for several times. Isn't it there a definite solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type

```
xrandr -s 1 && xrandr -s 0
```